# Updating order of child record

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got two tables:

**Parent**

| id |

**Child**

| id | owner | ordernr |

owner is a foreign key referencing Parent's id. There is a uniqueness constraint on (owner, ordernr)

Now, there are some gaps in the orders and I'm trying to fix them as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myView AS 
(SELECT childid, ordernr, n 
  FROM (SELECT child.id as childid, ordernr, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY parent.id ORDER BY ordernr) AS n 
        FROM Parent, Child WHERE owner = parent.id)
WHERE ordernr <> n)

UPDATE 
(SELECT c.ordernr, n
FROM Child c, myView WHERE childid = c.id) t 
SET t.ordernr = t.n
```

But I get: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

This error occurs when you try to INSERT or UPDATE columns in a join view which map to a non-key-preserved table.

You could use a **MERGE**.

For example,

```
MERGE INTO child c
USING (SELECT n
       FROM   myview) t
ON (t.childid = c.id)
WHEN matched THEN
  UPDATE SET c.ordernr = t.n

/
```